# EF Core DbPropertyValues is missing. Is there an alternative?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

In EF6 we have `DbPropertyValues` inside  `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure`

I am trying to migrate a EF6 library to .net Core. I have done most conversions, but I can't find an equivalent to DbPropertyValues which I use when comparing changes of an entity. What can I use instead? Is there an equivalent to System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure?